# Turn on Windows 10 monitor when VLC launches

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, multiple-monitors, vlc-media-player

I have a desktop computer I'm using to play videos over an HDMI cable connected to a TV. I use VLC to play video files on that computer and using the android program Remote for VLC (Stream Fork) to start VLC. The desktop is in a room separate from the TV.

When I was using Windows 7 on the desktop, launching VLC would both turn on the monitor and show the video on the TV. I recently upgraded to Windows 10. I can still launch VLC remotely, but neither the monitor nor the TV show an image immediately. I have to hit a key or move the mouse on the desktop to wake up the screen so that I can see the video on the TV.

I know the video has started, because the Remote for VLC app shows the video's progress.

How can I have the video be visible when I launch VLC?